# Determine if remote process main window is shown in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, process, remote-access

I'd like to determine whether a remote process has already shown its main window.

I already tried `Process.WaitForInputIdle()` and `Process.MainWindowHandle` but these informations cannot be obtained / executed from remote.

Also `Win32_Process` class from WMI does not provide informations about UI of the process.

Any other ideas?